# Ember tutorial - Server not starting after installing ember-cli-mirage

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-mirage

Following along with the ember tutorial and got to installing ember-cli-mirage [here](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/tutorial/installing-addons/).  After I install the add-on the server will not start.  I get to "Serving on http://localhost:4200/" and then it just hangs there.  When I try to kill the server via Ctrl-C it also hangs at "cleaning up...".  If I remove ember-cli-mirage from package.json and node_modules then everything will start again.

I have been able to dig around to get live server and other aspects running, but this one is giving me nothing to work with.  Are there any additional settings/pieces that the tutorial is missing or do I have a version/environment issue?  Is there a way to get additional information at startup (I know --verbose is not one)?

Vagrant: ubuntu/trusty-64 (14.04.5 LTS)

Node: v7.5.0

NPM: v3.10.8

ember-cli: 2.11.1

After more digging this appears to have something to do with Vagrant.  I ran through the same steps on my local Windows machine and it loads fine with Node v6.10.0.  I then tried that version of Node on Vagrant and left it running while I went out.  It ultimately took 19 minutes for the container to come up.  The full time was spent in Babel.  It doesn't appear to be a memory issue on the VM, not sure what the difference may be and no errors were reported.

Ember Server output from both environs:

**Vagrant**

`vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant/sample$ ember serve
Livereload server on http://localhost:4300
Serving on http://localhost:4200/`

Build successful - 1169101ms.

Slowest Nodes (totalTime => 5% )              | Total (avg)
----------------------------------------------+---------------------
Babel (19)                                    | 1106280ms (58225 ms)

**Windows**

`c:\projects\super-rentals>ember server
Livereload server on http://localhost:49153
Serving on http://localhost:4200/`

Build successful - 24208ms.

Slowest Nodes (totalTime => 5% )              | Total (avg)
----------------------------------------------+---------------------
Babel (19)                                    | 12332ms (649 ms)
SimpleReplace (2)                             | 4686ms (2343 ms)
Concat (8)                                    | 3411ms (426 ms)
Funnel: Addon JS (11)                         | 1289ms (117 ms)

Comment: Unable to reproduce, adding mirage added 4-5 seconds on a cold build but I was still able to get the server running. Did you let it sit for a while?

Comment: Ah, just saw your edit. The 5 second difference is surprising, whatever's happening sounds like it's being magnified in Vagrant somehow. I should investigate the difference in build time.

Comment: Without mirage the server comes up relatively quickly, although slower than Windows.  I had found the item below saying it always would be so wasn't concerned with 15-30s, but 20m to come online isn't maintainable

https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/6355

Comment: Added an edit to show build times with ember-cli-mirage in both environs